# JSON Parsing error JSON code verified correct, error persists

Tags: node.js, json, npm

I have tried to Clear Cache + --Force clear cache, have spent many days looking for a solution and problem persists when i try the 'npm install' command. See syntax below:

Please help!

```
npm ERR! file C:\Users\luisl\package.json
npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE
npm ERR! Failed to parse json
npm ERR! Unexpected token } in JSON at position 627 while parsing near '...tract": "3.0.6",
npm ERR!   }
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! '
npm ERR! File: C:\Users\luisl\package.json
npm ERR! Failed to parse package.json data.
npm ERR! package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Tell the package author to fix their package.json file. JSON.parse

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

Comment: can you copy the content of your package.json and share here so we can have clear idea of your problem. It seems it just have lack of comma (,) or you have more closing bracket

Comment: You package.json is bad formatted

Answer (score 0):

thanks for responding to my question Robert. I found that the Json not found Parsing error. was due to incorrect filing in the C: drive. when i moved the Json file to the correct pathway, it resolved the problem, C:\Users\YourUserName\eth-todo-list. save file here. Hope this helps someone in the future. make sure you are saving your Jsons in the right file directory.